# Wi-Fi Direct in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

According to documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifidirect.wifidirectdevice.aspx

it should be available on 8.1 store and it is, the problem is that each time it code below returns 0. Code taken from msdn example for Windows 8.

```
String deviceSelector = Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var devInfoCollection = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(deviceSelector);
```

Anyone knows if WiFi Direct is actually supported on Windows Phone?

Thanks